# How to speedup Silverlight (after xap file is loaded)?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

We are developing some silverlight 4 applications. They are a form of customization to a standard software (MS CRM) where pages are opened and closed constantly. So the startup performance is critical for us.
We already ensured that the xap files are cached so that upload time is not a big issue. But it still takes several seconds until our first screen comes up. And in the meantime the plugin area is simply blank. No feedback for the user.

That's a bad user experience and we are looking for possibilities how to minimize that "no feedback" time. What can we do to speedup the start of our Silverlight apps?

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce non-responsive time while silverlight application loads, is to show splash screen. Splash screen can be a simple .xaml file that contains image for your application. Typically we show full size image until application loads. Handling load times with splash screen is a standard technique. Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903962%28VS.95%29.aspx) URL on msdn for different options that you can set to splash screen.